# Using MinGW-w64 from MSYS2 with LibraryLink

Tags: windows, librarylink, c++, ccompilerdriver

I am looking to use the MinGW-w64 version of gcc, as bundled with [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/), with LibraryLink.

It was communicated to me that in recent versions of Mathematica, one may use the MinGWCompiler compiler driver with MinGW-w64 (the documentation page showing the use of GenericCCompiler is outdated).

In particular, it was confirmed to me that the code I included at the end of this post worked for at least one person. However, for me it does not work. At the `LibraryFunctionLoad` stage, I get

```
In[12] := add1 = LibraryFunctionLoad[add1lib, "add1", {Integer}, Integer]

During evaluation of In[12] := 
 LibraryFunction::libload : The function add1 was not loaded from the file C :\Users\mpi\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\add1.dll.
Out[12] = $Failed

In[13] := LibraryLink`$LibraryError
Out[13] = "Library load error 998: Invalid access to memory location.
```

I am looking for advice on debugging this and figuring out what causes this failure. Does it work for anyone else?

I tried this on two computers, and I see the same failure on both:

- Windows 7 with Mathematica 12.0.0
- Windows 7 with Wolfram Engine 12.1.0

---

Here's a minimal example to test with. This assumes that msys2 was installed at the default location. The example C code is from the `CreateLibrary` doc page.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

Needs["CCompilerDriver`MinGWCompiler`"]

$CCompiler = {"Name" -> "MinGW", "Compiler" -> MinGWCompiler, 
   "CompilerInstallation" -> "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe", 
   "CompilerName" -> Automatic};

add1src = "
  #include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

  DLLEXPORT mint WolframLibrary_getVersion(){
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return 0;
  }

  DLLEXPORT void WolframLibrary_uninitialize( WolframLibraryData libData) {
    return;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int constantzero(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
     MArgument_setInteger(Res, 0);
     return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }

  DLLEXPORT int add1(WolframLibraryData libData,
            mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    mint I0;
    mint I1;
    I0 = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    I1 = I0 + 1;
    MArgument_setInteger(Res, I1);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
  }

  ";

add1lib = CreateLibrary[add1src, "add1", "ShellCommandFunction" -> Print]

add1 = LibraryFunctionLoad[add1lib, "add1", {Integer}, Integer]

add1[10]
(* 11 *)
```

Comment: Windows 7 might be relevant. Do you have the Microsoft [UCRT update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) installed?

Comment: @ilian Thanks for the tip! Yes, I already have it installed. I downloaded the install package from this link: when running it, it says it's already installed. Also, executables compiled with this compiler do work. Even DLLs work: I used a MinGW-compiled DLL with an MSVC-compiled LibraryLink library, and that worked.

Comment: @ilian I got hold of a Win10 machine with M11.3, and it worked. However, the UCRT update on Win7 did not work.

Comment: I wonder if this would have worked if you did not link to the MathLink DLL, e.g. `"SystemLibraries" -> {}`. If so, this is most likely some kind of CRT-level incompatibility between what mingw uses and MathLink.

Comment: While MathLink is not my area, if this is really specific to mingw on Windows 7, the chances for a fix would be slim. The whole platform is just about obsolete.